# NPM Async Series Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, async.js

I am having an issue using the npm async module. The documentation suggests the following code structure will result in sequential execution of the functions added to the series array but when I run the following, I only get the "first" console.log. What is the issue?

```
var async  = require('async');

async.series([
  function(){ console.log("first")},
  function(){ console.log("second")}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `async.series`, you should provide each function with a callback function, which when executed it 'tells' async to move forward to the next function in line:

```
async.series([
  function(callback){ console.log("first"); callback();},
  function(callback){ console.log("second"); callback();}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`async.series` passes a `callback` that you must call at the end of each function:

```js
var async  = require('async');

async.series([
  function(callback){ console.log("first"); callback(null, 1); },
  function(callback){ console.log("second"); callback(null, 2);}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Async expects a callback to be called when each function is done, to then fire the next function etc.

```
var async  = require('async');

async.series([
  function(callback){ 
      console.log("first");
      callback(null, 'data'); // first arg is error
  },
  function(callback){ 
      console.log("second")
      callback(null, 'data'); // first arg is error
  }
], function(err, results) {
    // results === ['data', 'data']
});
```

The documentation is somewhat lacking in explaining this

Comment: This works for me but why do we have to pass a callback? I'm using this module so I can eliminate the complexity of chaining already-declared functions of asynchronous nature. Having to pass an arbitrary callback into a function declaration where I'll be executing other functions is a lot of clutter but I guess its the way the module works.

Comment: Because that's the only way `async` can know that you're asynchronous operations have completed, and it's time to move on to the next step.

Comment: Does the second argument of the callback get passed to the next function in the array? How would the second function retrieve that value?